# EMail link with custom paypal amount

Tags: paypal

I am currently using the payment request via email, created through paypal web site. I would like to know is there a way to create a link to send via email in which I can dymamically pass the amount. I tried to create custom buttons, but in this case I can set a specific amount for each button, or leave it empty and let the user to choose how much he has to pay.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to do this in PayPal Standard. You cannot dynamically pass this code into the email link. If you create a Donation Button (you must be accepting donations and a non-profit organization).

You can use the email button link that accompanies the donation button.
Here's how to create a payment button link:

1. Log in to your PayPal account.
2. Click Merchant Services near the top of the page.
3. Click Create payment buttons for your website under "Features you can use right now."
4. Click Create a button.
5. Choose the donation button type and follow on-screen instructions to create your button.

Note: If you don't see the Email tab, the option is not available for your button. This usually happens when you create a drop down box, input field, or the button has one or more codes and can't operate in the form of a hyperlink.

If you are not a non-profit and are not accepting donations then this option will not work for you. For Payments Standard there are no other Hosted Solutions that will allow your customers to click on the hosted link and choose their payment amount.

You could also create your own link and place an open source button on your site passing this code in:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="Youremail@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Enter an Amount">
<input type="text"   name="amount" size=8>
<br />Please Enter Amount (ex 100.00)<br />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted"><br />
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```